# Magento migration from Godaddy server to Amazon aws Ubuntu

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I migrated *magento host server from Godaddy to amazon aws ubuntu* . Everything working fine but when user proceed to checkout. An error appears on screen

Error : Warning:

> include(/var/www/html/includes/src/Payu_PayuCheckout_Model_Shared.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93  #0 /var/www/html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(/var/ww...', '/var/www/html/i...', 93, Array) #1 /var/www/html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload() #2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Payu_PayuChecko...') #3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Payu_PayuChecko...') #4 /var/www/html/includes/src/__default.php(23435): class_exists('Payu_PayuChecko...') #5 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('payucheckout/sh...', Array) #6 /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Payment_Helper_Data.php(68): Mage::getModel('payucheckout/sh...') ..........

but same code works fine on godaddy.

Payu module is not enabled. I tried running compilation again also.

Do I missing any Php or Apache configuration ?

Please help me. any suggestion that can resolve this error.

Comment: try to replace your .htacess from a fresh magneto.

Answer (score 0):

it might be your compilation is creating issue

Go to file

> `includes/config.php`

comment out line

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

with

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

if not commented

and remove dir includes/src

Comment: I tried solution you suggested. But I am getting still the same error.
can u suggest any other solution. Thanks Minesh

Comment: @Rohit "I am getting still the same error" if you have disabled compilation than error should not be same.

Comment: Flush all cache after disabling compilation

Comment: After disabling compilation and removing includes/src
got this error : 

Warning: include(Payu/PayuCheckout/Model/Shared.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: "Payu module is not enabled" from module config xml file ?

Comment: it was enabled in config.xml .after disabling its working
Thanks a lot